# Improves performance on R working with raster files

Tags: raster, r, remote-sensing, performance, landsat

I´m trying this code to look for NA and negative pixel values and replace it for 0. But it´s too slow. Any tip for improve the performance of it?

"all.files" is a list of address of the images. "r1" is the stack of Landsat images and "e" is the extents of some region of interest.

```
 for (i in 1:length(all.files)){ 
    r1<-raster(all.files[i])
    re1<-crop(r1,e)
    re1<-re1/10000
    re2<-as.matrix(t(re1))
    re1[which(is.na(re2))]<-0
  for (j in 1:length(re1)){
    if (re1[j]<0)
   (re1[j]<-0)}
writeRaster(re1,filename=paste(substr(all.files[i],80,86),"_crop2.tif",sep=""),format="GTiff",overwrite=TRUE)
}
```

Comment: fwiw, try using basename(all.files[i]) rather than substr.

Comment: Why are you coercing to a matrix? Just treat the raster object as a matrix and index appropriately. This will replace NA and negative values in a raster and keep it a raster object:  x[is.na(x) | x < 0] <- 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use reclassify:

```
for (i in 1:length(files)){ 
    r <- raster(files[i])
    r <- crop(r, e)
    r <- r / 10000
    outf <- paste0(substr(files[i], 80, 86), "_crop2.tif")
    r <- reclassify(r, c(NA, NA, 0, -Inf, 0, 0), filename=outf, overwrite=TRUE)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To assign raster values to 0, you can do something like this:

```
r <- raster('yourraster.tif')
r[is.na(r)] <- 0   #Convert all NAs within extent of r to 0
r[r < 0] <- 0      #Convert all negative numbers to 0
```

You dont need to convert it to a matrix or anything like that. So:

```
for (i in 1:length(all.files)){ 
  r1<-raster(all.files[i])
  re1<-crop(r1,e)
  re1<-re1/10000
  re1[is.na(re1)] <- 0
  re1[re1 < 0] <- 0
  writeRaster(re1,filename=paste(substr(all.files[i],80,86),"_crop2.tif",sep=""),format="GTiff",overwrite=TRUE)
}
```